# Use an excel formula to set the cell style?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet named "Data" with one column of data from a DB and a second column with unique keys we type in. We have UDF, `GETVALUE`, that looks up the cell by key and then returns the value from the cell beside it like, `=GETVALUE("VAL001")`.

The UDF returns a Double. The problem I'm having is that the formatting of that double can have real effects, "$0.05" means something very different than "5%", even though `GETVALUE` returns 0.05 in either case.

So... is there some way I can set the format on sheet one so it matches the format on the other? IE, if the value is a percent on one page, I'd like anyone referencing it to also be able to set to a percent as well. Can this be done with a UDF in the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit of playing, but I figured out a solution.

First I made a new UDF that returns the NumberFormat string, `GETFORMAT`. This is the same format as `GETVALUE`.

Then I used a conditional format with this formula"

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("%",GETFORMAT(Data1,"THECELL")))
```

This returns true or false depending on whether there's a % in the format. Then I make the true condition be a %, and the false be the $.

This isn't perfect, if you have more than one style it can get REALLY complicated, but it works for simple cases.